# jquery limit checkboxes in divs

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox, input

I want to limit the number of useable checkboxes in a form. I try it with the following jquery code

```
var limit = 2;
$('input.checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
    if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
        this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

and this works. But if input tag is inside a div tag, the jquery stops working.

example:

```
<div class='voteContainer'>
    <input name='vote1' value='1' class='checkbox' type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div class='voteContainer'>
    <input name='vote2' value='3' class='checkbox' type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div class='voteContainer'>
    <input name='vote3' value='3' class='checkbox' type='checkbox' />
</div>
```

how i have to change the jquery to work with this input tags in a div?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not wrap it inside a parent div and get count of all checkboxes which are checked?

```js
var limit = 2;
$('input.checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
    if($('#checkboxes input.checkbox:checked').length > limit) {
       this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="checkboxes">
<div class='voteContainer'>
    <input name='vote1' value='1' class='checkbox' type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div class='voteContainer'>
    <input name='vote2' value='3' class='checkbox' type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div class='voteContainer'>
    <input name='vote3' value='3' class='checkbox' type='checkbox' />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes thanks, i change it now like this and it works very well :)

Answer (score 1):

They're not siblings anymore. Count those that appear inside a `div` with class `voteContainer`, like this:

```
var limit = 2;
$('input.checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
    if($('div.voteContainer input:checked').length >= limit) {
        this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$("input[name='tech']").change(function () {
      var maxAllowed = 2;
      var cnt = $("input[name='tech']:checked").length;
      if (cnt > maxAllowed)
      {
         $(this).prop("checked", "");
         alert('Select maximum ' + maxAllowed + ' technologies!');
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="tech" value="jQuery" /> jQuery <br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="tech" value="JavaScript" />JavaScript <br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="tech" value="Prototype" /> Prototype<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="tech" value="Dojo" /> Dojo<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="tech" value="Mootools" /> Mootools <br/>
```